# Multi-line String to Tuple Dict in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples

I have a multi line string that I would like to convert into a tuple dictionary with Python 2.7

my string is:

```
data = '''1 George  1789 
2   John    1797
3   Thomas  1801
5   James   1817'''
```

and let's call the dictionary:

```
pres{}
```

I want the key to be 1 and the values it spits out to be "George" and "1789".

```
print pres[1]
```

should give

```
George,1789
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: None of this question uses valid syntax, do you want answers in valid syntax?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to coding and am not sure. I want the command print pres[5] to show James,1817

Comment: It's better to go through a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) then. And try something first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the text you can parse it in a comfortable way:

```
data = """1   George  1789 
2   John    1797
3   Thomas  1801
5   James   1817"""
rows = data.split('\n')
pres = {}
for row in rows:
    vals = row.split()
    pres[vals[0]] = (vals[1], vals[2])

pres
{'1': ('George', '1789'), '3': ('Thomas', '1801'), '2': ('John', '1797'), '5': ('James', '1817')}
```

You can of course change the `pres[vals[0]] = (vals[1], vals[2])` to `pres[int(vals[0])] = (vals[1], vals[2])` in order to have integer indices and not string indices.

Also, multiline strings involve three quotation marks instead of just 1.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Also thanks for being patient with me. I may have been a bit annoying since I am new at this.